# Parametrization of half circle in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm looking for a parametrization of the half-circle in the upper plane, going from $-1$ to $1$. Is $$\gamma(t):\begin{cases}[0,\pi]\to\mathbb C\\t\mapsto-e^{-it}\end{cases}$$ correct?

Comment: Looks good to me. I've tested the two ends and the mid point of the interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct.
$$ 
\gamma(t) = -e^{-it} = e^{i(\pi - t)} \quad (0 \le t \le \pi)
$$
is an arc on the unit circle with the argument of $\gamma(t)$ decreasing from $\pi$ to zero.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!